# RouterLink throwing error 'Cannot read property 'frequency' of undefined'

Tags: angular, angular4-router

In my angular 4 application, I have following HTML in view

```
<p>
    You are on dasrboard(firstlevel);
    <a [routerLink]="['/seconddashboard',{frequency:frequency, datefrom:datefromparam, dateto:datetoparam}]"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right" > Second Level (sc) </button></a> 
</p>
```

and following code in component

```
export class DashBoardComponent implements OnInit {

  frequency = '';
  datefromparam='';
  datetoparam='';

  constructor(private dataService:ChartdataService,private _alertService: AlertService) { 
  // this.InitChildComponents();
    this.frequency = 'daily';
    this.datefromparam='';
    this.datetoparam='';
}
```

but on page load it is giving error `Cannot read property 'frequency' of undefined`. Can someone please help me where I am doing wrong?

[image: Error in routes definition]

Answer (score 1):

you should use this key word inside constructor

```
 export class DashBoardComponent implements OnInit {

 frequency = '';
  datefromparam='';
 datetoparam='';

 constructor(private dataService:ChartdataService,private _alertService: 
 AlertService) { 
 // this.InitChildComponents();
   this.frequency = 'daily';
   this.datefromparam='';
   this.datetoparam='';
```

}

Comment: Still getting the same error. It is coming in HTML at line `<a [routerLink]="['/seconddashboard',{frequency:frequency, datefrom:datefromparam, dateto:datetoparam}]"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right" > Second Level (sc) </button></a>`.

Comment: <a [routerLink]="['/seconddashboard',frequency:frequency, datefrom:datefromparam, dateto:datetoparam]"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right" > Second Level (sc) </button></a> try this one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass and read data using angular router, you have to `stringify` passing data:

```
<p>
    You are on dasrboard(firstlevel);
    <a [routerLink]="['/seconddashboard', {
      queryParams: {
        'data': JSON.stringify({
          frequency: frequency,
          datefrom: datefromparam,
          dateto: datetoparam
        })
      }
    }]"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right" > Second Level (sc) </button></a> 
</p>
```

Routes should look something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'seconddashboard',
    component: DashBoardComponent
  },
  // other routes
];
```

And then, inside recipient component you can read passed data using `this.route.snapshot.data`:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params, Data } from '@angular/router';
// other imports

// @NgModule and other stuff

export class DashBoardComponent {
  frequency = '';
  datefromparam = '';
  datetoparam = '';

  constructor(
    private dataService: ChartdataService,
    private _alertService: AlertService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { 
    // this.InitChildComponents();
    this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(t => {
        // may be you also need to do `JSON.parse(t['data'])`
        console.log(t['data']);
        // may be I missed something in path below, but you can easily correct it based on 'console.log' above
        this.frequency = t.data.frequency;
        this.datefromparam = t.data.datefromparam;
        this.datetoparam = t.data.datetoparam;
      });
  }
}
```

And don't forget to use `this` inside constructor, like `this.frequency = "SOMETHING"`.

Comment: It is giving build error in `data` of `routes` part in frequency, datefromparam and datetoparam.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in question for your reference please.

Comment: @Nitesh, I see, my fault. Is it OK to include the data to URL? Are values a regular strings?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to achieve but it is also giving `Cannot read property 'frequency' of undefined` when trying to assign values of these variable in `routerLink`.

Comment: @Nitesh if you want to include this data as params in URL, you should follow totally other way... In my example you just pass data to another component without affecting the URL.